# Sudarsana Homam

Tags: homam, sudarsana

Can Sudarsana homa be performed by women? What is the time to perform to perform Sudarsana homam? As we are performing homams I do know that it should start by 5 am and end by 9 am if there are 4 Brahmins. Nowadays due to shortage of homam performing and assisting Brahmins we start by 6 am  and end by 11/30 [poornahuti by 11/30].

Comment: Everything can't be taught online.For this specific reason one should go to a living SatGuru.And I'm sure that u don't have one and u are doing homams on ur own by reading books.That's ridiculous to say the least.God bless the people for whom u are doing the Homas.:)

Comment: @Rickross-- You do not want to teach online--By God's grace I am more knowledgabel than you because we have performed 10 mhomams till time. God blessed those who gave chance to us. You need not say that. You undersand the concept of homam first and speak. If you do not know do not answer. sinple ignore.  Many temple preists perform homams which in a hurried way. We are not doing that. So learn before answering. I have seen women performing sudarsana homa which is against the rule of homa. That is why I asked the question. I will ignore your answers from now onwards bcoz it does not fulfil.

Comment: I know how to do homas already.We are being taught by our first guru.But i ll not try teach someone online.The questions u are asking here wud not have existed if u had a guru.U shud be asking ur Guru such questions.

Comment: @Rickross--You yourself are telling there is no guru as this is kaliyuga-- contradictory remarks--What are the basic step in homa? You won't teach online I know,It is not teaching. Explain the first step.

Comment: Where did i say- that there is no guru in kaliyuga?I myself have two.

Comment: go back and see the answers

Comment: @Rickross--Everybody will be having one Guru. You do not believe in first guru. Hence keeping second guru. Let God forgive you on this.The pundit or purohit do not know much hence I am not believing them and started my own performing homams. If you have guts you also serve public in affordable cost by doing homam for them  because you have learnt homam from somebody as per your words.

Comment: Who told u that everyone will have one guru?Do u know how many gurus Sri Ramakrishana had?I'm surprised that u don't even know some basic things and performing critical stuffs like doing a homam on ur own.Its like playing with fire.Anyways its upto u to decide.

Comment: In those days we can find true Gurus. But nowadays all are false gurus.That is why you cannot distinguish a person and having two gurus and hearing what they say and impose on others. Do not advise that I am playing with fire etc. You do not have self confidence . That is why u r not performing  any homams although you say u know. We do on charitable basis which will save us.